# Deleted /home on Debian Server; No SSH possible

Tags: linux, ssh, debian

My Debian root server has 3 RAID-1 (they were preconfigured). One of them is a 1980GB drive (/dev/md4) mounted as /home. I tried to split it, to make a second partition for my databases.  But as I found out it didn't had a partition table.

I tried to create a new partition on it with fdisk and it has accidentally overwritten the old one. I tried to reboot, but now I'm not able to SSH into the server anymore.

I booted a rescue image of my hoster, created the partitions correctly and put the /dev/md4p1 into the fstab file as /home. But I am still not able to SSH into my server.

Is there any way to see what the problem is while booting? I couldn't find any log file, etc.

Comment: Have you tried logging into a root account whose home directory is not under ‘/home’?

Comment: Yes I did. But I instantly get a "connection refused".

Comment: Since you are booting from a rescue disk, have you configured SSH as supplied by your rescue disk then try logging in?

Comment: You claim to have fixed, it, but I would guess that it wasn't entirely fixed.  Something probably breaking during the normal boot, and it is dropping out to a rescue prompt or something.  As for figuring out the problem.  See if your hosting provider can give you KVM access or something.

Comment: I already tried to get KVM access but they don't offer it.

Comment: Not sure what to tell you then.  Maybe use the rescue mode to make a final backup, then reinstall.

Answer (score 1):

You need out of band management to fix a problem with booting, network, or sshd. Usually some kind of console provided by the hypervisor or hosting provider.

Increase the logging level of `sshd`. Copy the sshd_config file to a new one on a different port, and start it with  `sshd -d -f`.  Open any host firewall to listen on this new port. If you can get authentication working on the debugging sshd, move whatever changes you make into the regular service sshd.

Also start a network packet capture so you can see if any connection was made.

---

Confirm what the restore time objective is for this box. It may be faster to build a new host and restore any important data from backup.

---

Personally, I do not partition data volumes, not after the initial OS install. Create LVM physical volumes on entire disks instead.  In this case, that could be:

- take a backup of /home
- destroy /home and use it from LVM with  `vgcreate data /dev/md4`
- `lvcreate` volumes for /home and your database
- restore the /home backup

Answer (score 0):

Boot on rescue image , and modify :

1. `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` to allow root login with password

   or
2. `/etc/passwd` the home dir of a privileged user to `/username` instead of `/home/username`
   copy `.ssh` folder to `/username/.ssh` ...

After reboot , you can have a ssh access , and i will recommend you to backup all files and rebuild a new one .